# Guess the coin toss

Tags: strategy, coin-tossing

You and your friend are put in two different rooms with just a coin and no way to communicate. You both toss the coin at the same time.

Your task is for at least one of you to guess correctly what the other one has tossed.
You may think ahead of a strategy that will help you.

note: 
The coins are regular H/T.
There is no way to communicate after you enter the rooms, and you can't hear what the other one said. This is a logical question, not tricky.

Comment: If you've seen this puzzle somewhere, don't forget to add the source. And welcome to Puzzling SE :)

Comment: heard the riddle somewhere, not on the internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first person will guess the same thing they got and the second person will guess what they did'ny get. If they got the same thing (TT/HH) the first person will be right and if they were different (HT/TH) then the second person will be right.

Comment: I was about to answer this, nice job.